# DOMException The result must not have attributes in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to include an custom component for a modal dialog. But I always get an exception

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have attributes`

Component **PipelineConfiguration**

```
import  React from 'react';
import { OwcModalDialog, OwcButton } from '@one/react';
import './index.css';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { store } from "../../containers/App/prelex.store";

export default function PipelineConfiguration() {

    const handleVisibleChange = observer(function () {

    });

    const { pipelineSelection, showConfiguration, showConfigurationModal } = store;

        return (
        <OwcModalDialog visible={showConfiguration} size="md"  onVisibleChange={(ev) => handleVisibleChange(ev.detail)}>
                <div slot="header">Configure "{pipelineSelection}" pipeline</div><div slot="actions">
                <OwcButton variant="primary" onClick={() => showConfigurationModal(false)}>Configure</OwcButton>
            </div>
        </OwcModalDialog>
        )
}
```

Imported in **Main-Component**

```
...
import PipelineConfiguration from "../../components/ModalConfiguration";
...

const App = observer(function () {
    const { showConfiguration } = store;

return (
    <><div id="modalConfiguration">
    { showConfiguration ? (
        <PipelineConfiguration />
    ) : ('')}
 ...
```

Comment: Your error mentions `CustomElement` but you don't reference it anywhere in the code you've shown. Maybe start looking where you use that.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I get the component from an external design kit. I will investigate it. I wanted to prevent that I might have done something wrong